# Do we need to explicitly pass php.ini's location to php-fpm?

Tags: php-fpm, php.ini, upstart

I am seeing a strange issue where my `php.ini` is not used if I do not explicitly pass it to `php-fpm` when starting it.

This is the upstart script I am using:

```
start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=lo)
stop on runlevel [016]

pre-start script
    mkdir -p /run/php
end script


expect fork
respawn
exec /usr/local/php/sbin/php-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php/php-fpm.conf
```

If PHP is started with the above, my `php.ini` is never used, even though it is in `Configuration File (php.ini) Path`.

This is the relevant part from `phpinfo()`:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path           /etc/php/
Loaded Configuration File                   (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
Additional .ini files parsed                (none)
```

If I modify the last line of the upstart script to point `php-fpm` to  `php.ini` explicitly:

```
exec /usr/local/php/sbin/php-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php/php-fpm.conf -c /etc/php/php.ini
```

Then we see that the `php.ini` is loaded:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path           /etc/php/
Loaded Configuration File                   /etc/php/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
Additional .ini files parsed                (none)
```

**Why is this the case? Is this a quirk in php-fpm?**

---

Minor update: This also seems to be a problem for php5-fpm installed using `apt-get`.

I did a test install in a Ubuntu Server 12.04 virtual machine by running the following:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx php5-fpm
```

PHP-FPM and nginx were started after installation and everything seemed fine. I then uncommented php's settings in nginx's configuration and placed a test `phpinfo()` file to inspect PHP's settings.

The relevant bits are:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path           /etc/php5/fpm
Loaded Configuration File                   (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed                /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
```

I noted that no `php.ini` was loaded either. However, if I go to `/etc/php5/fpm`, I can see that a `php.ini` exists. I also checked the start up scripts for PHP-FPM and the `-c` parameter was not used to link the ini file to PHP. This can potentially be confusing for people who would expect php.ini to be loaded automatically by PHP-FPM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we do not explicitly need to pass the `php.ini` file to `php-fpm` when starting it.

Let's first deal with the `php5-fpm` installed using `apt-get`. Once I restarted the server, the `php.ini` was loaded. It was strange but it worked.

Back to my question.

Notice that I compiled PHP with `--with-config-file-path=/etc/php/`. The problem is caused by adding a trailing slash to the folder when using `--with-config-file-path`.

In my case, I ran `make clean` to clean out the old compiled binaries. Then I ran configure with `--with-config-file-path=/etc/php` (notice that there is no trailing slash for the folder). Then `make` and `make install`.

Once this is done, you will find that the `php.ini` in `/etc/php` is automatically loaded, regardless of whether we pass it to php-fpm using the `-c` switch or not.